# Convert a string to a time format

Tags: c#

The application is an event scheduler, so the user should set a time in a `Textbox` and by submitting the time it should be converted from a `string` to `time format`

and this is the part of the code

```
public void btn_click()
{
    var Time = textbox.text;
    **convert string to time format
    Leaps.save(xname, xdate, xtime, xprt);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: well, using @tim-schmelter 's answer i first auto-corrected the user inputs to appear as a time-format while hes in action and validate the input at the end to submit it as time-format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` and `DateTime.ToString`:

```
DateTime timeOfDay = DateTime.ParseExact("1200am", "hhmmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = timeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I'm using `InvariantCulture` to prevent culture isues.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/gplQ5N)</kbd>

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to validate user-input:

```
DateTime timeOfDay;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact("1200am", "hhmmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out timeOfDay))
{
    // valid format, timeOfDay is initialized
}
```

Comment: thanks.. it just needed some modifications, but iv got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve your desired results using value converters. They will allow you to modify any content displayed in your textbox before it is actually rendered. So if anybody would enter '1350am', you could do some string analysis and return '13:50 am' based on the input to the textbox. I assure you, it's way more easy than it sounds. Those links should get you going:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546926%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html